# Problema con un ListView y sus elementos

Tags: android, android-studio

Resulta que tengo una lista en donde se visualizan ciertos partidos de Fútbol y sus fases, a la hora de desplegar la vista y mostrar sus elementos va perfecto, el problema ocurre en lo siguiente ya que cada partido contiene un campo fase así:

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "equipo1_id": 1,
  "equipo2_id": 2,
  "fecha_hora": "...",
  "fase": "Grupales",
  ...
 },
 {
  "id": 7,
  "equipo1_id": 3,
  "equipo2_id": 9,
  "fecha_hora": "...",
  "fase": "Eliminacion",
  ...
 }
]
```

Utilizo ese campo `"fase":` y lo muestro en un TextView para saber cual partido corresponde a cada tipo de partido, para que tengan idea la lista queda algo asī.

```
Grupales //<-- TextView        
Equipo 1 vs Equipo 2 

Grupales
Equipo 1 vs Equipo 2

Eliminacion
Equipo 1 vs Equipo 2

Eliminacion
Equipo 1 vs Equipo 2
```

Lo que quiero lograr es que quede de esta manera:

```
Grupales //<-- TextView        
Equipo 1 vs Equipo 2 
Equipo 1 vs Equipo 2
...
...

Eliminacion
Equipo 1 vs Equipo 2
Equipo 1 vs Equipo 2
...
```

la idea es esconder el TextView con un `.setVisibility()`.Pero cual seria la forma correcta de implementar esto? Debería usar el valor que me devuelve `fase` y compararlo con los demás elementos?

Este seria el método Asíncrono para listar los partidos y hacer set del Adapter:

```
public class programacion extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    JSONArray results = new JSONArray();

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            results = WebService.listaProgramacion(token);
            return true;
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSONException",e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IOException", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
        super.onPostExecute(success);
        dialog.dismiss();
        if (success){
            lista_partidos.setAdapter(new AdapterPartidos(getActivity(), R.layout.partidos_item_list, results));
            lista_partidos.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Y este es mi Adapter:

```
public class AdapterPartidos extends ArrayAdapter<JSONObject> {
JSONArray data;
Context contexto;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public AdapterPartidos(@NonNull Context context, int resource, JSONArray data) {
    super(context, resource);
    this.data = data;
    this.contexto = context;
}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView fase;
    TextView equipo1;
    TextView equipo2;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.data.length();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder v = null;
    if(convertView == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.partidos_item_list, null, false);
        v = new ViewHolder();
        v.fase = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.fase);
        v.equipo1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.equipo1);
        v.equipo2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.equipo2);
        convertView.setTag(v);
    }
    else {
        v = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    try {
        JSONObject content = data.getJSONObject(position);
        v.fase.setText(content.getString("fase"));
                v.equipo1.setText(content.getJSONObject("equipo1").getJSONObject("equipo").getString("nombre"));
        v.equipo2.setText(content.getJSONObject("equipo2").getJSONObject("equipo").getString("nombre"));



    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Pero puedes mostrar el código que estas utilizando._?

Comment: @Gytree listo, disculpa la demora Añadi el codigo del Asynctask y el Adapter que utilizo para listar los partidos y sus fases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yo comprobaría si se cambia de fase. La posición 0 del array tendrá una fase nueva seguro, ya que es la primera posición. Si no es el elemento 0 del array se comprobará que la fase actual es distinta de la anterior. Si es distinta se añade la fase, si no, se deja el campo en blanco. Cómo mejora al código puesto mas abajo, te propongo que "escondas" el textview para que no ocupe espacio en el xml.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder v = null;
if(convertView == null) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.partidos_item_list, null, false);
    v = new ViewHolder();
    v.fase = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.fase);
    v.equipo1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.equipo1);
    v.equipo2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.equipo2);
    convertView.setTag(v);
}
else {
    v = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
}

try {
    JSONObject content = data.getJSONObject(position);
    if (position == 0){
       v.fase.setText(content.getString("fase"));
    }
    else {

        String previousFase = data.getJSONObject(position - 1).getString("fase");
        if (previousFase != content.getString("fase")){
            v.fase.setText(content.getString("fase"))
        }
    }
            v.equipo1.setText(content.getJSONObject("equipo1").getJSONObject("equipo").getString("nombre"));
    v.equipo2.setText(content.getJSONObject("equipo2").getJSONObject("equipo").getString("nombre"));



}
catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return convertView;
```

}

Un saludo!!

Comment: Hola Carlos. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, esto aclara totalmente mi duda con respecto al problema del TextView que se repite con cada objeto. Saludos!